# Renaming folders/files in Zend Studio

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

When I develop projects in zend studio, whenever I want to rename a file or folder it checks prerequisites and takes up to a minute, on some bigger projects it even has thrown an Out of Memory exception.
How do I disable this feature in Zend Studio / Eclipse

**Note:** I know the purpose is that the program is trying to help me locate files that might be affected by the name change, but I'm willing to leave that responsibility to me.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this through the resource viewer rather the php explorer